# ffmpeg output doesn't have the audio

Tags: bash, sound, ffmpeg

I'm working on a 24/7 music streaming channel. This script should stream the `bg.mp4` on loop and play mp3 files from a folder called `mp3`. Currently streaming the mp4 file on loop works but no audio is played.

Here is my current script:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel info -y -re \
    -re -stream_loop -1 -i bg.mp4 \
    -f concat -safe 0 -i <((for f in ./mp3/*.mp3; do path="$PWD/$f"; echo "file ${path@Q}"; done) | shuf) \
    -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -b:v 3000k -maxrate 3000k -bufsize 6000k \
    -framerate 25 -video_size 1280x720 -vf "format=yuv420p" -g 50 -shortest -strict experimental \
    -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ar 44100 \
    -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/
```

Running ffmpeg version 4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1

I'm relatively new to ffmpeg and any hints towards fixing this would be great.

My output logs: https://pastebin.com/aVbsWwgF

========= UPDATE =========

After a while of researching I finally got it working by using map: `-map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0`

Final code:

```
ffmpeg -y -re \
    -re -stream_loop -1 -i bg.mp4 \
    -f concat -safe 0 -i <((for f in ./mp3/*.mp3; do path="$PWD/$f"; echo "file ${path@Q}"; done) | shuf) \
    -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -b:v 3000k -maxrate 3000k -bufsize 6000k \
    -framerate 25 -video_size 1280x720 -vf "format=yuv420p" -g 50 -shortest -strict experimental \
    -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 \
    -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/
```

Comment: Is there a Ubuntu product involved, if so what version?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Try using gstreamer instead

Comment: @peter Why isn't ffmpeg good for this? Could you send any kind of documentation of gstreamer?

Comment: Hey! This is neat! Can you post the output of a section of ffmpeg while it's running (redacting streaming keys)? We might be able to tell from the (verbose) ffmpeg output what's going on. Please paste a snippet in the question above. Also get rid of the loglevel info, so it's more verbose.

Comment: @popey I've added them to the post. I apologize for taking so long.

Comment: gstreamer is likely already inztalled if you using ubuntu. Type "man gst-launch-1.0"